# Window Location Replace with hash?

Tags: javascript, hash

Can I put a hash in `window.location.replace()` somehow? It doesn't seem to work.

```
window.location.replace("url#hash");
```

Comment: what do u want to do?
May be what can be done thru' window.history object.
plz explain more.

Comment: @Nitesh I'm using a lightbox called fancybox and in it I have a form and when that is sent I use window.location.replace() to navigate to another page where a lightbox is opened if a hash value is set...

Comment: so you want to change current URL with some new URL, right?

Comment: *"It doesn't  work"* is not a proper problem statement that tells us anything of value. Also need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry about that. It doesn't navigate to the url. I think it is because with the hash value it tries to navigate to the same address and with a hash value there I guess it wont refresh the page if `url#hash` already is `url#hash`. It works if I put `url?dummy#hash` in the replace instead

Comment: No it won't if the only difference is the hash. But you can listen for hash change and do whatever is needed. Why do you really need to reload same page?

Comment: @charlietfl It's actually not the same content. I send a form inside the lightbox and the content that opens up in the new lightbox (but with same url) is different. I bet there are a lot of other ways of doing this but it works by using the dummy trick. I tried to do stuff with location.hash but with the location.replace and the same url it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Not enough detail provided as per [mcve]. We can only guess

Answer (score -3):

First things first.

```
window.location
```

is a Object. You cannot invoke a replace method on a Object.
Secondly you cannot call the replace method with only one argument.
If what you want to achive is to place a #hash in a link you can do this, by creating a `<a href="#hash">Insert text here</a>`, or changing the `window.location.href` property as follows

```
window.location.href += "#hash";
```

Please update your question for more accurate answer

Comment: This is completely inaccurate. Suggest you read the `location` docs and stop mixing string concepts with the actual `location.replace()` method